# Calculate Jaccard similarity coefficient with a matrix

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula, network-programming, vba

I have used the search function, and have not found anything regarding how to create Jaccard similarity coefficient for each cell within an already made matrix, and I'm open to both R or Excel.

Here is my sample matrix (450x450 bib coupling matrix):

data:
[image: data]

Using the bibliometrix package in R, I attempted to to find the Jaccard similarity coefficient for each reference, but hand calculations proved it to be incorrect:

```
S <- normalizeSimilarity(NetMatrix, type="jaccard")
NetMatrixTable2 <- as.matrix(S)
```

Jaccard Matrix:
[image: Jaccard Matrix]

I want to find another way to conduct Jaccard similarity coefficient, but have it replace the cell like output in bibliometrix package.

Answer (score 1):

The `vegan` package includes the Jaccard metric:

Ex.:

```
library(vegan)
data(varespec)
vare.dist <- vegdist(varespec, method="jaccard")
mds <- metaMDS(vare.dist)
ordiplot(mds, t="t")
```

Comment: The package has the function, but not for a matrix form.